How to connect timestamp of one sheet in another sheet
I have created one google sheet called attendance which will be working as frontend and i have created one more reference sheet as RE sheet and pulled all the data  using IMPORTRANGE Function next I have to see the Timestamp in my reference sheet when frontend sheet got edited that too for  every column and I don't want that to be   visible in frontend sheet ..
Kindly someone help me out with this ..
i'll be sharing both the google sheets
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13jfdYbRcvrA4y_Sj4OM3PWr6JNGrNHKdoSufaj4IFgg/edit#gid=0  (Reference sheet)
1KVpXNYYbe6BdRqqT0XnuJbtWEu0hj5olRvaHL714wNM  ( original sheet )
Need solution code for this

Sheet is not shared. You need to include your current attempts, where you struggle and what is your expected output (using dummy data)
